# Get the column numerically closest to a specific column from all columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder if it is possible to get the column whose value is closest to a specific column from all data frames without iterating over all the columns. I.e. if there is some built in functionality or an efficient way to do this?
I see so many elegant solutions here, I felt like there must be for this scenario too

Example:

```
|--A--|--B--|--C--|--closest to C--|
|  1  |  2  |  3  |       B        |
|  5  |  2  |  6  |       A        |
```

Thanks for any tips and insights.

Comment: I don't see an option without iterating over columns. It starts with the issue, that *closest* is not really defined: maximum number of identical values, minimum difference of squares, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract all columns without `C` by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html), get absolute values and get column by minimal values by [`DataFrame.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
df['new'] = df.drop('C', 1).sub(df.C, axis=0).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C new
0  1  2  3   B
1  5  2  6   A
```